# spring CORS and angular not working : HTTP status code 403 error

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-rest

I am new to angular and spring-security.I am having problem with CORS when trying to log in from angular login-form page using basic authentication to the rest endpoint. My Angular code is running on http://localhost:4200 and rest end point on http://localhost:8181. My angular login-form tries to make request to http://localhost:8181/token which I have specified in my login controller. Even though I have added cors configuration in server side, I get this error :-

Failed to load http://localhost:8181/token: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

(angular) login.service.ts:-

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8181/token';
    const encodedCredential = username + ':' + password;
    const basicHeader = 'Basic ' + btoa(encodedCredential);
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-wwww-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Authorization' ,  basicHeader);
    const opts = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.get(url, opts);
  }
```

}

(spring) SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/image/**",
            "/book/**",
            "/user/**"
    };

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS)
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
 @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","DELETE","PUT","OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

LoginController.java

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/token")
    public Map<String, String> token(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String remoteHost = request.getRemoteHost();
        int portNumber = request.getRemotePort();
        String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();

        System.out.println(remoteHost + ":" + portNumber);
        System.out.println(remoteAddr);


        return Collections.singletonMap("token", session.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: CORS seems to be deactivated (https://spring.io/understanding/CORS)

Comment: I have added CORS configuration in SecurityConfig class as shown above in code block

Comment: problem is with your authentication mechanism, somehow it's not able to authenticate user. So it returns 403 status

Comment: when i use traditional approach where the class implement Filter interface and perform filterChain.doFilter for every request/response for cors handling instead of  spring CorConfigurationSource it works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this configuration. It should work fine for you.

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Since you are using spring security / authentication. You should use setAllowCredentials(true).

Comment: No matter what I do I'm getting 403. I am using KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with your code, I've tried a bunch of similar code.

Comment: @ancm - it is very difficult to understand the exact problem without looking at the stack trace. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153070/keycloak-spring-boot-not-authenticating-rest-endpoint or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493809/keycloak-integration-with-spring-boot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051923/keycloak-angular-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck with this problem for 2 days and by adding `@CrossOrigin("*")` in `controller` solved my problem.

note: you can put your `origin address` instead of `*`

Comment: Thank you, I was searching for a solution for this problem, for almost 6 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@CrossOrigin("http://your-foreign-site/")
@RequestMapping("/token")
```

instead.

Comment: But I want to add cors configuration in global level. Not in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<mvc:cors>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
</mvc:cors>
```

to your `web.xml` to allow connections from all hosts

Origin: https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Answer (score -1):

inside your controller use the value from a .properties file

@Value("${cors.site.enable}")
private String site;

use @crossOrigin(site)