# Keycloak Integration with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

How to integrate keycloak with a spring boot application. Do we have to give all the resources and its role permission in application.properties? Then what is the use of keycloak.json? Then I need some clarification on those export settings in the admin console of keycloak. Do we have to include that file in the config of application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't want to add keycloak.json if spring-boot adapter is added and all the configurations are made in application.properties.Export in keycloak console is used for exporting all those roles,resources,policies and all other configurations made in the console.That is just to export the setting of that particular realm.

Answer (score 2):

1) First add these dependencies to your `build.gradle` (I'm using gradle, but it's the same for `pom.xml` if you're a Maven guy):

```
// keycloak
compile 'org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-adapter:2.5.1.Final'
compile 'org.keycloak:keycloak-tomcat8-adapter:2.5.1.Final'
```

2) Then provide your Keycloak config in the `application.properties` file (by this time you should have configured your realm and added a client via Keycloak web-ui):

```
keycloak.realm=[YOUR-REALM]
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://[YOUR-KEYCLOAK-INSTANCE-ADDRESS]:[PORT]/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=[CLIEND-ID]
keycloak.credentials.secret=[YOUR-CLIENT-SECRET-ID]
keycloak.cors=true


keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=insecure stuff
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/test-endpoint-1/*

keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].name=admin stuff
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].authRoles[0]=[ROLE-2]
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/test-endpoint-2/*
```

Here I'm allowing any one to access everything at `/test-endpoint-1/*`, whereas admin users with the [ROLE-2] role can access anything under `/test-endpoint-2/*`.

Ah, forgot to mention, the client `Access Type` is `bearer-only`. And yes, with this setup you don't need `keycloak.json`.
Hope this helps :)

### UPDATE

The new API has changed a little bit, so given the latest versions:

```
kotlinVersion = '1.3.10'
springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
keycloakVersion = '4.6.0.Final'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:${keycloakVersion}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // keycloak
    compile 'org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter'
}
```

`application.properties` will in this case look like the following:

```
keycloak.realm=[YOUR-REALM]
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://[YOUR-KEYCLOAK-INSTANCE-ADDRESS]:[PORT]/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=[CLIEND-ID]
keycloak.credentials.secret=[YOUR-CLIENT-SECRET-ID]
keycloak.cors=true
keycloak.enabled=true

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=insecure stuff
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/test-endpoint-1/*


keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].name=admin stuff
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].authRoles[0]=[ROLE-2]
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/test-endpoint-2/*
```

Comment: yes it helped.Doesn't need to have keycloak.json.How do i push cliams for claim-based policy?

Comment: do you mean roles? could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: var context = $evaluation.getContext();
var identity = context.getIdentity();
var attributes = identity.getAttributes();


if (identity.location=='mumbai') {
    $evaluation.grant();
}

Comment: how do i check the user attribute based policy?

Comment: You can make use of the Keycloak's REST API. Another option is to use Spring Security provider from Keycloak and get the principal object.